# spyder python how to re-open Variable Explorer

Tags: python, spyder

I accidentally closed the variable explorer on my Pythone(Spyder)...
Does anyone know how I can reopen it?
If I must reinstall the program, then I will but I just want to see if there is a way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Go to **View**/**Panes** and select **Variable Explorer**.

Answer (score 6):

Just use combination of shift+ctrl+v

Answer (score 2):

You can go to view then in view click on window layout then in that click on reset to spyder default which will give you the default layout of spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to tools(look at the dashboard at top middle)
and select reset spyder to factory dafaults and click ok
You will get your default spyder console.